# Creating boxplots from dataframes without merging into one

Tags: python, boxplot

I have 4 dataframes that look the same but contain data from different months. This is what they all look like. They have a date and contain process times. The last row is an indicator, but not important.

```
 Freigabe Fauf  Transport/Auslagerung  Qualitätsprüfung  Packen  Auslieferung  Gesamt  Komp Werk
 2018-09-07                    1.0               1.0     2.0           1.0     4.0          2
 2018-09-10                    1.0              11.0     6.0           2.0    19.0          1
```

I want to try to merge the two datafram in one dataframe and plot the times sorted by the time ("Gesamt", "Qualitätsprüfung", "Packen" etc.) and the months.
So this is what I tried for "Gesamt" and "Auslagerung/Transport".

```
z = pd.concat([m1df1i, m2df2i, m3df3i, m4df4i])

a = z[['Gesamt']].groupby(z["Freigabe Fauf"].dt.month).boxplot(z)

b = z[['Transport/Auslagerung']].groupby(z["Freigabe Fauf"].dt.month).boxplot(z)
```

When I plot only one, the result ist fantastic for me (I'm still a beginner).

[image]

but when I execute everything they merge into one.

[image]

How can I avoid it? I need only single plots for every Kind of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the two boxplots are displyed on one figure, to avoid that, you should add, in your code, `plt.show()` each time you use `boxplot()`. With that, you will have one plot per figure.